# Why is this code not creating files?

Tags: java, file, stack-overflow

Im trying to create files with those methods:

```
private boolean createFileMain(String path){
    File file = new File(path);
    if(file.isDirectory()){
        return this.createDirectory(file);
    } else if(file.isFile()) {
        return this.createFile(file);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean createFile(File file){
    if(!file.exists()){
        if(file.getParentFile().exists()){
            try{
                if(file.createNewFile()){
                    return true;
                }
            }catch(IOException e){
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if(this.createDirectory(file)){
                this.createFile(file);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean createDirectory(File file){
    if(!file.exists()){
        if(file.mkdirs()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The paths of the files:

> /Users/username/Directory/Accounts/
>
> /Users/username/Directory/Srcs/file1.txt
>
> /Users/username/Directory/file2.txt

When I try to run this the following method throws a `StackOverFlowError`.

```
public void writeInFile(String path, List<String> content) {
    if ((new File(path)).exists()) {
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter(path, "ASCII");
            for (String contentItem : content) {
                writer.println(contentItem);
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            //DO STUFF
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            //DO STUFF
        }
    } else {
        this.createFileMain(path);
        this.writeInFile(path, content);
    }
```

Why is no of the files created?

Comment: have you debugged it? also: add logging in your catch blocks, at least you'll be informed if something goes wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `createFileMain` only creates files which already exist.

You don't need to create a file to write to it, all you need is the directory you want to write it into.

```
public void writeInFile(String path, List<String> content) {
    File file = new File(path);
    File parent = file.getParentFile();
    if (parent != null && !parent.exists())
        parent.mkdirs();

    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(path, "ASCII")) {
        for (String contentItem : content) {
            writer.println(contentItem);
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        //DO STUFF
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the JavaDocs on `isDirectory()` etc.? For `isDirectory()` it says:

> returns true if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists and is a directory; false otherwise

So if the directory doesn't exist you get false and don't create one. Then you continue trying to write and create and write etc. until you get the StackOverFlowError.

To fix the stackoverflow you should check the return value of your create file, e.g.

```
boolean created = this.createFileMain(path);
if( created ) {
  this.writeInFile(path, content);
}
```

To fix your file/directory creation you need to check whether the file already exists and otherwise create it (optionally also creating the parent directories via `file.getParentFile().mkdirs()`).

The problem is that you should know whether you want to create a file or a directory, since you can't tell by the name alone whether the path is meant to be a directory or file name (unless you invent some markup like always ending a directory path with a separator or requiring files to always have an extension). If you want to write some content you need to create a file anyways, a directory would break your code again.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean createFile(File file) {
    if(!file.exists()) {
        if(file.getParentFile().exists()) {
            // ...
        } else { // In this case, neither file nor its parent exist
            if(this.createDirectory(file)) {
                this.createFile(file); // HERE, you're calling the same method again
            } else {
                // ...;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I believe you want to replace the line marked `HERE` with `this.createFile(file.getParentFile());`. Here what happens is that your function recursively calls itself with the same arguments, so nothing ever happens, and your program gets stuck in a loop until it runs out of stack memory.